# Comparing datetimes in javascript in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have to compare two date times in javascript. The dates I have are of the form

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
```

I am using the below code for it

```
var date1 = new Date("2015-08-20 09:38:20");  
var date2 = new Date("2015-08-20 08:00:00");
```

The problem here is that when I use "/" in place of "-", I get the expected results. But when for this format I do

```
date1 > date
```

It returns false

Using momentJs is not an option for me and also I am getting the dates from soemewhere so would have to preserve the format. How do I compare the dates of the above given format in javascript

Comment: use momentjs, much easier to manage datetimes and will be a nice long term solution for different issues

Comment: Yups, I totally agree with you but not an option for me in this case.

Comment: `date1 > date2 === true` actually in this case.

Comment: Which browser is this in? It works for me in chrome. The only thing I did notice is in your example you compare `date1 > date` rather than `date1 > date2`

Comment: date1 > date2 is true in Chrome. But, doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: This is typical of JavaScript dates. All browsers seem to treat date strings differently. My experience is write your own parser if you know the format you want to deal with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var date1 = '2015-08-20 09:38:20';
var date2 = '2015-08-20 08:00:00';
var date1Updated = new Date(date1.replace(/-/g,'/'));  
var date2Updated = new Date(date2.replace(/-/g,'/'));
console.log(date1Updated > date2Updated);
```

Comment: Different output in firefox

Comment: While the method is good but it doesnt work, the precise reason being 
date1Updated would be '2015/08-20 09:38:20'

Comment: It works if it is changed as `new Date(date1.replace(/-/g,'/'))`

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the given behavior, but you could try
converting the date1 and date2 variables to miliseconds and storing those in separate vars since Jan 1st 1970.

```
var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
var date2_ms = date2.getTime();
```

this gives ( for your given example )

```
1440056300000
1440050400000
```

and in a comparison

```
date1_ms > date2_ms
```

**returns true**

Comment: Try in firefox. You can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try using js.do, an online Javascript IDE ,I am able to get the particular behavior there

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of JavaScript dates. All browsers seem to treat date strings differently. My experience is write your own parser if you know the format you want to deal with.

Something like the below will work. Feel free to tidy it up and make it more generic for your own use.

```
function parseDateString(dateString) {
    var dateParts = dateString.split(' ');
    var dateOnlyString = dateParts[0];
    var timeString = dateParts[1];
    var dateOnlyParts = dateOnlyString.split('-');
    var year = dateOnlyParts[0];
    var month = dateOnlyParts[1] - 1;
    var day = dateOnlyParts[2];
    var timeParts = timeString.split(':');
    var hours = timeParts[0];
    var minutes = timeParts[1];
    var seconds = timeParts[2];
    return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

jsfiddle for test: http://jsfiddle.net/04nh4q9w/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getDate(dateString) {
     //This function assumes that the dateString will always be of the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
     var dateParts = dateString.split(' ');
     var dateStr = dateParts[0].split('-');
     var timeStr = dateParts[1].split(':');
     var dateTimeArr = datestr.concat(timestr)
     return new Date(dateTimeArr[0], dateTimeArr[1]-1, dateTimeArr[2], dateTimeArr[3], dateTimeArr[4], dateTimeArr[5]);
}

var date1 = getDate("2015-08-20 09:38:20");  
var date2 = getDate("2015-08-20 08:00:00");
```

**date1 > date2 will be true for any browser.**

Answer (score 0):

```
    function convertTo24Hour(time) {
        time = time.toUpperCase();
        var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
        if(time.indexOf('AM') != -1 && hours == 12) {
            time = time.replace('12', '0');
        }
        if(time.indexOf('PM')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
            time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
        }
        return time.replace(/(AM|PM)/, '');
    }
```